# How to insert line break in between ranked items in SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to ask how to insert a line break in sql

For example the image below I have a few items which I ranked by the highest price to the lowest price. I would like to insert a line break in between the various groups of items.

[image]

My query is as such

```
with
    item_list as (
        Select 
        item_name, price
        from table_A
        where month = 3 and year = 2020
order by price desc 
        )

    SELECT *        
    FROM (      
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.item_name
    ORDER BY price DESC) as rank, *     
    From item_list a)       
    WHERE rank <= 5
    ORDER BY item_name
```

Comment: SQL is query language, not presentation language. Use your UI layer for fancy visualization, leave SQL do data retrieval job

Comment: thanks but im just finding out if this is feasible

Comment: You'd need an extra order by column, then you would simply manually insert a bunch of NULL values using UNION ALL. It's a bad idea. Perhaps `ROLLUP` or `CUBE` might help

Comment: @Rosellx . . . There is simply no concept of "line break" in a table.  That is not SQL.

Comment: I see, thank you..